# How to download build files from Visual Studio Online?

Tags: visual-studio

I am a newbie in Visual Studio and have my projects deployed on Visual Studio Online. How can I download the **successful build** files from Visual Studio Online to my machine. Because as far as I know, after successful completion of the build, we can only download logs as zip file.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late to answer this question, but in case someone still looking for solution, I used this one:

When creating build definition, in "Build Defaults" pane selected "Copy build output to the following Source Control folder".
In textbox I typed "$/[Your project root]/Drops" where [Your project root] is the root name of your project base.
After that I can build with this definition and in "Drops" folder start appearing folders with build results.

Answer (score 0):

I know this old but I just had this problem. Assuming you have a task of "Publish Artifacts". You can click on the result of a build and there will be an Artifacts tab that let you download the folder created in the publish artifacts task mentioned.